# XSD TO XML Conversion

Tags: xsd

I want to write a java program, Input - XSD File I need to retreive all the element name from the xsd and need to create an xml file as an output with the retreived element name. If anyone of you have the sample code, please share it.

Thanks

Comment: XSD already is XML. You use it to validate other XML files. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: Isn't XSD a xml file? Are you talking about creating an instance of the XSD?

Comment: Thanks, I want to parse the xsd file using anyone of the parser and need to produce the resultant in the xml flavour.

Comment: I suggest you explain with an example.

Comment: I want to write a java program, Input - XSD File I need to retreive all the element name from the xsd and need to create an xml file as an output with the retreived element name

Answer (score 0):

You are not rephrasing your question,but still i found some suggestions for you.See if its useful for you.Please check the following link...

http://www.narendranaidu.com/2010/04/xsd-to-xml-and-vice-versa.html

Answer (score 0):

Alright use [JAXME](http://ws.apache.org/jaxme/xs/) or [XSOM](http://xsom.java.net/) to parse your schema and use DOM or JDOM to write the element names to new xml

Comment: Hi Pangea, Thanks for the above comment do you have sample code snippet

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create a sample XML from schema ..you can use XMLspear tool to do that.
http://www.donkeydevelopment.com/